# Load JSON array from a database SQLITE

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sqlite, multidimensional-array

I have the following code in an array for Javascript JSON:

```
params = {
    "fighters": [
        {
            "name": "Muhammad Ali",
            "nickname": "The Greatest"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chuck Liddell",
            "nickname": "The Iceman"
        }
    ]
};
```

Now I have "N" variable data "name" and "nickname" from a database SQLITE.

The idea is to show all the "nick" and "nickname" that exist from the database iteratively.

How I can fill it?

I tested with a FOR that runs all the arrangements and I charge them, for it did something like this:

```
params = {
    "fighters": [ show[i] ]
};
```

It does not work.

I hope I explained correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You should let us know what show[i] outputs and then we can tell you how to fix it

Comment: so what do you want to do? *get* the data from the database, or *display* it? That's totally different stuff...

Comment: Get the data and load it into "params" and then send the JSON to another application.

Answer (score 0):

That will retrieve all fighters names:

```
var len = params.fighters.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      console.log( params.fighters[i].name );
   }
```

To change fighters names values do the following:

```
var len = params.fighters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      params.fighters[i].name = 'Your_Fighter_Name';
    }
```

Hopefully i have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

assuming we're in the `fetchAll(function (error, rows) {})` callback using `node-sqlite` (meaning rows is an array of objects, with the keys in the objects being the column names):

```
var params = { "fighters" : [] };

rows.forEach(function (row) { 
    params.fighters.push({name: row.name, nickname: row.nickname});
});
```

Remember, JSON is subset of JS, it is *not* it's own language. It's *NOT* a programming language. You can't "do" anything in JSON, as it is not a programming language. You can't iterate, recurse, fill... you can do that with JS.

Sorry for repeating myself, but apparently a lot of people mistake JSON for something it isn't. I'm not assuming you do, but it can't be said too often ;-) How you want to send the JSON I can't tell you, as there is no information in your question. If you want to do this via a byte-based protocol such as HTTP you might want to use `JSON.stringify()` to get a textual representation of your object that you can send over the network.

See my version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpL4c/2/ .

Comment: Thanks for your help and clarification, but I still can not work. Look at this link will show the code I'm using (as well as including your own): http://jsfiddle.net/dpL4c/

Comment: The idea is to load all the rows returned from the database in the array "params".

Comment: see my link. Why didn't you give this code out in the first place? That would have been easier, ad your problem didn't have anything to do with SQLite... Just give as much information as you have (but not too much), and people will be able to answer quickly and correctly.